# Usb run script when plugged in ubuntu different pc

Tags: ubuntu, usb

**I need to run some script from usb**, for example in windows open as "folder, media" and it is pretty easy, and i need the same in Ubuntu
Whenever i try to find out i get the same answer *https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto* but it doesn't make sense
I won't be able to type this code **in everyone pc** and updating "user dev". Is there any decisions. I am not creating virus or so,
i just want to create a media player which will read a media from usb in some folder. If it is possible to run on windows i thought
in Ubuntu also should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Windows but what I know is that it does not have a great reputation regarding security, at least until recently. Auto-executable binaries on a USB disk allowed a lot of malicious activities in the past. That's why, by default, no serious user-oriented Linux distribution will allow a script to auto-execute on USB drive insertion. Generally, the execution bit is even removed on those drives, so that a user can not even execute anything directly on the drive (you can only "open ... with"). I guess you are facing a dead-end.